# Fully identifying the system behavior

Tags: signal, control

"Any arbitrary nonzero input signal x(t) would be suitable for fully identifying the system behavior, by observing the corresponding output y(t)." Is this statement true? I could not prove it.

Comment: Yes. A PRBS generator can be used for identifying a system behavior by observing the output. This can takes some time ... Only use the properties of correlated sequences. http://users.abo.fi/khaggblo/npcw21/submissions/27_Garcia-Gabin&Lundh.pdf

Comment: If I am not wrong, it is only true for "minimum phase shift system" (?) : https://www.egr.msu.edu/zhug/Publications/Journal%20Articles/PRBS%20closed-loop%20system%20identification%20error%20with%20integration%20control.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Any arbitrary nonzero input signal x(t) would be suitable for fully identifying the system behavior, by observing the corresponding output y(t)." Is this statement true?

Yes, assuming the system is linear.

Take the Laplace transform of a known input, and the Laplace transform of the corresponding output, divide the latter by the former, and you have the transfer function of the system.

To find the output corresponding to some arbitrary input, take the Laplace transform of this arbitrary input. Multiply by the transfer function. Take the inverse-Laplace transform of the result. That is the output corresponding to your arbitrary input.

Answer (score 0):

If the system is linear, the Dirac's pulse supplied as input x(t) to the system is enough to identify the system itself.

Comment: ok for an "available" system. PRBS generator can be used in a functioning "live" plant ... without disturbing it. Because PRBS is "organized" "noise" (?).

Comment: Also seen somewhere (?) that a PRBS signal is "equivalent" to Dirac impulse (because of the autocorrelation function is equal to 1 at t=0 and zero everywhere else ?